# Change existing row of database by query in java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to update a row in mysql...for that I used update query when update button pressed, but it not works...even not getting any error...So difficult to find out why it not works?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{
    try
    {
        String b="";
        String query1="update salesbill set `TaxAmount`='"+b+"' where SONumber = ?";
        PreparedStatement   pst=conn.prepareStatement(query1);
        pst.setString(1,sonum.getText()); //sonum is textfield where values passed for SONumber

        pst.setString(1, amt.getText());    //amt istextfield variable
        b=amt.getText();

        System.out.println(query1);

        pst.execute();
    }
    catch(Exception g)
    {
        g.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you tried debugging code ?

Comment: Yes sir...i tried and on console query prints like -----     update salesbill set `TaxAmount`='' where SONumber = ?

Comment: `amt.getText()` and `sonum.getText()` could you verify ?

Comment: By using sonum.getText() I passed value to the '?' and amt.getText() is for updating value to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to comment-out

```
 pst.setString(1, amt.getText());
```

As it is overwriting

```
pst.setString(1,sonum.getText());
```

And, your query expects `SONumber`

**==Updated==**

As OP mentioned in his/her comment that, he/she was trying to update `TaxAmount` which is `amt.getText()`. So, updated my post.

```
String query1="update salesbill set `TaxAmount`=? where SONumber = ?";
PreparedStatement   pst=conn.prepareStatement(query1);
pst.setString(1, amt.getText()); 
pst.setString(2,sonum.getText()); //sonum is textfield where values passed for SONumber   
pst.execute();
```

Please refer **[PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)**, to use appropriate method to set your value.

Comment: Thank you so much Ravi sir  :) problem solved